# Proof of a matrix norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

I have been struggling with how to prove the following:

$$\begin{align}
\left\|A^k\right\| \le \left\|A\right\|^k
\end{align}$$

I can prove it for $k=2$, and so I expect induction to work, but I have no idea how to carry it out.

Comment: Which norm are you using?

Comment: The standard frobenius two norm, sorry.  (The square root of the sum of the squares of all the entries).

Answer (score 3):

In general, you expect this to hold for norms that are submultiplicative, i.e. $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\,\|B\|$. Then
$$
\|A^{k+1}\|=\|A^kA\|\leq\|A^k\|\,\|A\|\leq\|A\|^k\,\|A\|=\|A\|^{k+1}.
$$

Comment: Glad I could help.